# Is it possible to prune ethereum full node without having to stop geth client?

Tags: geth-debugging, full-node, state-trie-pruning

Does anyone know how to prune ethereum geth full node for an application which requires a non-stop running full node ?somehow like the way bitcoin does pruning ( removing older blocks automatically while syncing)